# Are [chunked-encoding] [chunked] [http-chunked] duplicates?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I've just wrote a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629504/python3-threadinghttpserver-fails-to-send-chunked-encoded-response) regarding [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and I've found at least 3 tags that seems to be very similar (or duplicates).

[chunked-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chunked-encoding)
Chunked encoding involves transferring the body of a message as a series of chunks, each with its own chunk size header.

[chunked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chunked)
Chunked transfer encoding is a data transfer mechanism in version 1.1 of HTTP in which data is sent in a series of "chunks"

[http-chunked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-chunked)
The http-chunked tag has no usage guidance

Anyone knows whether those tags refers to different topics or are they actually duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those three tags mean the same thing and should be synonyms.  In theory "chunked-encoding" could be implemented on multiple protocols, but all the usage of it here appears to be HTTP/HTTPS related.  Its [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chunked-encoding/info) also specifically mentions HTTP.

[chunked-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chunked-encoding) should be the canonical tag.  It has the most usage and a decent [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chunked-encoding/info).  The other two tags should redirect to it.